# Force route to instantiante new controller/view pair instead of changing model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, router, ember-router

I would like to display a certain controller/view pair multiple times simultaneously. Problem is that the route changes the model on the current controller instead of creating a new one.

Is it possible to force a route to instantiate new controller? I've tried messing with the callbacks and hooks in Ember.Route but I can't find any way to make it behave like this.

Comment: how does your template look like? are you also aware from the existence of the `itemController` option for a `{{#each}}` helper or an `ArrayController`?

Comment: I'm merely trying out a prototype first so I can still shape the template any way I want. I started with a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/6WV2U/1/) but got stuck on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display multiple models simultaneously, it seems like having the route point to a single model that changes doesn't map well to what you're trying to do. The router was not designed to add additional views to a display unless you use nested routes. You could try overriding the [`renderTemplate` hook](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate) in your route and use [`render()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render) to specify which controller is used, but that doesn't help you with multiple controller/view pairs being displayed simultaneously.

Instead, I would try using one of the ways to specify a custom controller. When you have a collection of things to display, the simplest way is with the [`#each` helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each) in your template.

```
{{#each product in products itemController='myControllerName'}}
```

If you'd like to specify a custom view class, you can do that also.

```
{{#each product in products itemController='myControllerName' itemViewClass='App.MyView'}}
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, an alternative approach to getting a context that gets a new instance every time is by creating a **component**. This is more heavy weight, though, and you would probably need to refactor some of your code, moving the controller logic into the component.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected the router wasn't designed for this. Using each or components might be the way to go then. I would however like the URL to point to the last viewed model. Basically what I'm trying to create is an interface where a new route view partially 'slides' in over the previous view. Like in the Spotify web player: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5FaWt.jpg animates into http://i.stack.imgur.com/YDnU9.jpg. I suspect I need to update the URL manually then, but would that be possible with the router?

Comment: I don't use spotify, so I can't say for sure, but from your screenshots, it looks like you could use the above `#each` + `itemController` param to get your 1st screenshot to display all the artists. But then add a nested route with a dynamic segment that has the ID of the artist you've zoomed into for details to get your 2nd screenshot. When you click an artist in the list, transition to this new route. You can use an observer on the selected model to do your UI transition, and if it makes sense, an `{{outlet}}` with a nested template.

Comment: That would work for an overview page + artist details page. But from that 'artist' page you can click through to other 'artist' pages. These would then be layered on top of each other. The URLs are just /:artist_id, without any nesting. The problem is when I want to transition to another artist, it doesn't create new controller that I can layer on top of it, but just changes the artist on the topmost artist controller. Perhaps I should just forego the router for this, but a user should still be able to go to a page using the /:artist_id URL, only then it doesn't show any layering.

Comment: That's why I suggested using an observer in the overview page's view to do the transitioning. The template of the nested route might not be used. In the overview page, have a collection of all artists. Then have a separate collection of zoomed-in artists. When the zoomed-in artists change, your view can observe this, show the detailed view of the new artist and transition to it. All this logic can be in your overview controller/view. The nested route is purely so that the state of the last zoomed-in artist is saved and can be loaded later if the user goes to that URL.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. The artist route can basically manage a stack of artist components. That would work I guess. However, it still feels like a hacky solution. For example, it wouldn't cover a case like this: Page A -> page B -> page B -> page A -> page C. It would be nice if there was a way of using something like a Cocoa UINavigationController in Ember.

Comment: Not sure I follow. What's wrong with A -> B -> B -> A -> C? The fact that there are duplicates? Your collections can be regular old arrays, so I don't see any problem with that. The visual stack can be backed by an array data structure as an instance variable on your controller. You only want to save the state in the URL of the last page, correct? So the url would look like /artists/C. If you refreshed, you'd lose the stack, but you'd stay on artist C. If this helped you answer your question, please accept it. Otherwise you may want to try asking in ember discuss or IRC for more discussion.

Comment: It certainly helped, thanks. I tried to implement such a solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/130. The problem is that when I want to layer multiple controllers they have to be rendered in the correct order. For example: *Controller A item 1, Controller B item 1, Controller A item 2* will be rendered as *Controller A item 1, Controller A item 2, Controller B item 1*.

Comment: If need a different controller, have you tried [`render`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_render)? But you might be better off making a component. I.e. instead of using Controller A vs Controller B, use component A vs component B. The controller abstraction is more for state and context. A component may be better suited for you in that it's more for isolating a UI element.